# Examples of current densities

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment, magnetostatics

I am trying to imagine how do the continuous current density look like.

When we speak about charge density, if it is discrete, one can picture multiple point charges in a region in space. If the charge distribution is continuous you can consider a charged object.

I assume if we are considering a discrete current charge distribution, you can think of  multiple wires, in which a current flows.

Now what are some examples of the 2 following cases:

1. Contiuous current charge distribution.
2. Localized current distribution in a vacuum, which is what I consider when I try to use the multipole expansion for a current distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a uniform charge density described by a function $\rho(x)$ and a current density $\vec{J}(x)$ is a fiction one uses mathematically to approximate the macroscopic behavior of charges.

Real charges in the world are quantized, this is an experimental fact that has also theoretical underpinnings (dirac showed that if there exists 1 monopole, electric change had to be quantized).

When you don't look close enough, a bunch of "point" charges like electrons in a conductor move roughly like a uniformly charged liquid that is described by a current density $J(x)$.  However when you examine it closely, you see it is lumpy: the true current may look like a bunch of delta functions.

In 1 dimension, you can model a current mathematically as follows:

$$J(x, t) \approx \underbrace{\rho}_{n q} v \hat{x}$$
Here you assume it's just a current density travelling in the x direction.

But actually, it is an approximation for a lumpy stream of charges travelling at some velocity v.
$$J(x, t) = \sum_k q \delta(vt-x-k \Delta X) \hat{x}$$

This macroscopic approximation is explained in some detail by Jackson Electrodynamics, very first chapter.